# Why won't Calendar find my appointments

Tags: macos, calendar

I had previously used Calendar search, but lately (since Sierra?) it won't seem to find my appointments.

One example, I saw a Dr Wong some years ago, and was checking the date.

I searched for "Wong", and Calendar even suggested "Dr Wong", but showed `No Results`. A manual search found the appointment in September 2014.

Is there anything I can change to make Search work?

Spotlight Search found my Contacts, and Calendar for "Dr Wong"